# Visualizing $S_3 \rtimes D_4$

Tags: finite-groups, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups, semidirect-product

I am trying to visualizing $S_3 \rtimes D_4$ following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnRcc9eINaQ). Here, $S_3$ is the symmetric group over three symbols and $D_4$ is the dihedral group of order $8$. The semidirect product is defined as follows as per the definition given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product).

**Outer semidirect product:**

Let $G$ be $G = S_3 \rtimes_\varphi D_4$, $S_3 \triangleleft G$,  and $D_4 < G$. Let $Aut(S_3)$ denote the group of all automorphism of $S_3$. The map $\varphi : D_4 \to Aut(S_3)$ defined by $\varphi (h) = \varphi_h$, conjugation by $h$, where $\varphi (h) (n) = \varphi_h (n) = h n h^{-1}$ for all $h$ in $D_4$ and all $n$ in $S_3$, is a group homomorphism.

Together $S_3$, $D_4$, and $\varphi$ determine $G$ up to isomorphism.

So, $G = S_3 \rtimes_\varphi D_4$ is defined as follows.

1. The underlying set is the Cartesian product $S_3 \times D_4$
2. The operation, $\cdot$, is determined by the homomorphism, $\varphi$: 
   $$
   \cdot : (S_3 \rtimes_\varphi D_4) \times (S_3 \rtimes_\varphi D_4) \to (S_3 \rtimes_\varphi D_4) \text{ s.t. }\\
   (n_1, h_1) \cdot (n_2, h_2) = (n_1, \varphi(h_1)(n_2), h_1h_2) = (n_1, \varphi_{h_1}(n_2), h_1h_2)
   $$ 
   for $n_{1,2} \in S_3$ and $h_{1,2} \in D_4$.

Now, I go by each concept as it is done in the video.

To do that we need to know the Cayley graph of $S_3$ and $D_4$.

$S_3$:

[image]

According to this wiki article $Aut(S_n) = S_n$. So, the Cayley graph of $Aut(S_3)$ will be same as above.

$D_4$:

[image]

This is where I am stuck. How can one guess the homomorphism $\varphi : D_4 \to Aut(S_3)$ just by eyeballing the these two Cayley graphs?

Comment: Is $S_3 \rtimes D_4$ discussed in that video?  I only see a different example mentioned around the 12-minute mark.  Anyway, there are a handful of different choices of a homomorphism $\varphi:  D_4 \to \mathrm{Aut}(S_3)$, and they will yield different semidirect products.  (One can only identify $\varphi(h)$ as conjugation by $h$ after the semidirect product has already be constructed, since this conjugation takes place inside the semidirect product.)

Comment: $S_3 \rtimes D_4$ is not discussed in the video. But I thought I should be able to do it following the video. Are all the semidirect products constructed from different homomorphisms isomorphic to each other?

Comment: I suppose some of them will turn out to be isomorphic, but not all of them.  (It's definitely not true in general that semidirect products using different homomorphisms are isomorphic to each other.)  For example, if $\varphi$ is the trivial homomorphism, sending every element of $D_4$ to the identity in $\mathrm{Aut}(S_3)$, then the semidirect product is just the direct product.